# How to map from JPA Object in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

good day all: I have a little issue I want you help me to resolve.
My problem is the next, I have to find the shorter distance of the stores according to google maps and according the latitude and longitude, anyway, I have the query that do these,
my problem is when I call to `jparepository` it returns an array and I need to return me with a specific format.

This is my end-point I'm trying to get from `jparepository`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "api/promos/distance/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> distance(@RequestParam(required = false) Double latitude, Double longitude, Long radius) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(locationDAO.findDistance(latitude,longitude,radius));

    } catch (Exception ex){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

this is my repository with the params and return 2 values

```
@Query(value = "select sp.id as id, \n" +
            "          ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) \n" +
            "      * cos( radians( sp.latitude )) \n" +
            "      * cos( radians( sp.longitude ) - radians(:longitude)) \n" +
            "      + sin( radians(:latitude) ) \n" +
            "      * sin( radians( sp.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance \n" +
            "        from promo_locations sp \n" +
            "having distance < :radius ORDER BY distance ASC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> findDistance(
            @Param("latitude") Double latitude,
            @Param("longitude") Double longitude,
            @Param("radius") Long radius);
```

and it show me this

```
[
    [
        1,
        137.94383549078196
    ],
    [
        2,
        137.94383549078196
    ]
]
```

but I need to show me in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "distance" : 137.94383549078196
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "distance" :137.94383549078196
    }
]
```

If someone knows how to map or how to convert I will thank you so much

Comment: In the return type `List<Object>`, what is `Object`'s actual type?

Comment: really I don't know just return like this
```
[
    [
        1,
        137.94383549078196
    ],
    [
        2,
        137.94383549078196
    ]
] 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [this](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-native-query-results-entities/) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)
basically you need to define `SqlResultSetMapping` for your native query